# how to solve The requested URL was not found on this server issue before magento2 installation?

Tags: magento2, error, 404

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
127.0.0.1
Apache/2.4.37 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1a PHP/7.3.0

Comment: Can you give a bit more details ? What kind a url you are trying to reach ?

Comment: http://localhost/magento  I have unzip the magento zip in this folder

Comment: can you please confirm that you added the proper document root at webserver level?

Comment: yes I have confirmed.